# Remote Exchange Powershell using WSManConnectionInfo or Command Window (security)

Tags: c#, security, powershell

While developing in C# using Powershell Runspace and WSManConnectionInfo I noticed some strange behaviour when testing the same connection (with identical domain user) from the powershell command window.

**OK:  Remote Powershell using Command Window (user without permission)** (failed as expected)

```
# Connecting to a Remote powershell using non authorized domain user.

New-PSSession -ComputerName MY-EXCH-SERVER -Credential $null
New-PSSession : [MY-EXCH-SERVER] Connecting to remote server MY-EXCH-SERVER failed with the following error message :
Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
```

[image: From Console - Powershell command]

**NOT OK: Remote Powershell connection through WSManConnectionInfo from VS2015 with the same user as before** (success but it shouldn't because its the same user)

```
// When I do the below with the SAME user I am using in Powershell cmd window
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
    new Uri("http://MY-EXCH-SERVER/PowerShell/"),
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
    PSCredential.Empty
);
connectionInfo.SkipCACheck = true; // can be ignored
connectionInfo.SkipCNCheck = true; // can also be ignored
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Default;
this.currentRunspace =  RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
this.currentRunspace.Open();
[...]
// The connection is established, but the user does not have access actually
```

[image: From Visual Studio using WSManConnectionInfo]

**UPDATE**
When I try to open the Url from a Browser I get `401 - Unauthorized` as expected.
But still, it is still possibile through the C# code I have posted here

**UPDATE 2**
I noticed that the `WSManConnectionInfo` uses some Kerberos Authentication (in this case) and get successfully logged in.

Can anyone explain me what are the differences between CommandLine and WSManConnectionInfo and why i get successfully authenticated using one but not using the other?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`New-PSSession -ComputerName MY-EXCH-SERVER -Credential $null` cannot be compared with `WSManConnectionInfo` in Visual Studio.

But `New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://MY-EXCH-SERVER/PowerShell/`does.

I also noticed almost every user (within the domain) has access to the Exchange Powershell using the command I mentioned - But they have limited access (For example they cannot run "Get-TransportAgent").

In other words, domain user have access to exchange shell cmdlets dependent on their Active Directory permission but all can usually connect to it